# AngularJS directive: get restrict type in link phase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to get the selected restriction type of the directive instance I added to a page? That means can I check for A or E through an attribute?

Comment: you can detect it easily, given that you get element and its attrs list injected in link function

Answer (score 1):

You could check that inside your link

**Directive Link**

```
link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var directiveName = 'test', requireType = '';
    if (element.hasClass(directiveName))
        requireType = 'C';
    else if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(directiveName))
        requireType = 'A';
    else
        requireType = 'E';
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the best thing I can do, but can break in upcoming releases. I would like to have a attribute or function belonging to the API.

Comment: @dec I think only attribute api can contain a function.,how can you define funcion for class